"How to fix 'onReceive overrides nothing' error in Kotlin for BroadcastReceiver in Android?"
I am trying to implement a BroadcastReceiver to detect incoming phone calls and start a service for call recording in my Android application using Kotlin. However, I am encountering the following error in Android Studio:
package com.example.voicenote.receivers

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager

class PhoneCallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            val serviceIntent = Intent(context, CallRecordingService::class.java)
            context.startService(serviceIntent)
        } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            val serviceIntent = Intent(context, CallRecordingService::class.java)
            context.startService(serviceIntent)
        } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            val serviceIntent = Intent(context, CallRecordingService::class.java)
            context.stopService(serviceIntent)
        }
    }
}

I’ve also added the necessary permissions (READ_PHONE_STATE, RECORD_AUDIO, etc.) in my Android manifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.voicenote">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    
    <application
        android:label="voicenote"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <receiver android:name=".receivers.PhoneCallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>

I’m getting the following error in the PhoneCallReceiver class:
'onReceive' overrides nothing

app/build.gradle
    plugins {
        id "com.android.application"
        id "kotlin-android"
        // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    }
    
    
    android {
        namespace = "com.example.voicenote"
        compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
        ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId = "org.eierc.voicenote"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
            minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
            targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode = flutter.versionCode
            versionName = flutter.versionName
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        

source = "../.."
}

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this issue? What am I missing?

That's all correct, AFAICT. Did you try cleaning your project? (Under the Build menu.) Recent versions of Android Studio seem prone to getting hung up on non-existent errors, at least in my experience. Cleaning usually it straightens out, for me anyway.

I have cleaned project but did not help

Oh, Flutter? You might want to add a tag for that, too.

Yes its flutter but i have added kotlin codes under app/src/main/kotlin and i believe its a kotlin problem not flutter.

I wouldn't think so, 'cause Kotlin's override error message is different. It would be 'onReceive' overrides nothing. Also, override isn't an annotation in Kotlin; it's a keyword. I thought that error message looked a little odd. Maybe the error stems from some intermediate, generated class? I'm not familiar with Flutter at all.

Yes. 'onReceive' overrides nothing. Is the message
